# Как выбрать из строки?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Объясните, пожалуйста, есть строка:

`<td><span class=small>1.</span><br><a href='/roder/re3rr70' title='0r0t3 (1et).jpg'>picture</a></td>`

Мне надо выбрать из неё `/roder/re3rr70` и `0r0t3 (1et).jpg` и конкатенировать результат, чтобы получилось такая ссылка: `http://roder/re3rr70/0r0t3 (1et).jpg`, но застрял на таком:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = "<td><span class=small>1.</span><br><a href='/roder/re3rr70' title='0r0t3 (1et).jpg'>picture</a></td>"
>>> d = re.findall(r"<a href='(.+?)'>(.+?)</a>", text)
>>> print d
[("/roder/re3rr70' title='0r0t3 (1et).jpg", 'picture')]
```

То есть у меня выводится все, заключенное между тегом `<a></a>`, а я не знаю, как написать условия, чтобы после тэга `href=` выводилось значение title, а остальное отбрасывалось. Объясните, как задать условия?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я правильно понял ваш вопрос:

```
import re
text = "<td><span class=small>1.</span><br><a href='/roder/re3rr70' title='0r0t3 (1et).jpg'>picture</a></td>"
m = re.search(r"<a href='([^>]+?)'[^>]*title='([^>]+?)'[^>]*>", text)
if m:
    print 'http:/%s/%s' % (m.group(1), m.group(2))
```

выводит

> http://roder/re3rr70/0r0t3 (1et).jpg

**UPD:**
Во-первых рекомендую почитать про регудярные выражения вообще, например на википедии. Хотя их синтаксис немного варьируется в зависимости от языка программирования, но в целом везде одно и то же.
Во-вторых прочитайте документацию по библиотеке re (первая ссылка по запросу re в google).

По поводу этого примера:

1. [^>] означает любой символ, кроме '>'. Это нужно, чтобы не прочитать лишнего.
   Например, регулярка 'z.*z' на строке "adszazzbzasd"  будет соответствовать "zazzbz", а не "zaz" как хотелось бы. Еще для этого есть ленивые квантификаторы, но я не помню синтаксис.
2. Часть регулярки заключенная в скобки называется группа. Она нужна, чтобы вытащить эту часть из строки.
   m - объект типа re.Match. if m - проверка на то,  что в строке нашлась подстрока удовлетворяющая выражению. m.group(i) возращает часть строки, соответствующую группе с номером i.

Comment: вот,с этого поподробнее!интересует именно условия - ([^>]+?)'[^>] и ([^>]+?)'[^>]*>,а также логика условия if m,ну и m.group(1) и (2),ведь мне надо разобраться а не просто скопипастить,не все время решать задачи путем помощи

Comment: Может, вместо

> `r"<a href='(.+?)'>(.+?)</a>"`

использовать 

> `r"<a href='(.+?)' title='(.+?)'>.*</a>"`

вам же аттрибут title еще нужен.

Comment: Вот это `href='([^>]+?)'` и `title='([^>]+)'` немного странные условия. Наверное, правильнее что-то вроде: `href='([^']+)'` или еще лучше `href='((?:[^']|(?<!\\).)+)'` и аналогично для title.

@tukan, скажите, что именно вам не понятно? На всякий случай: [ Regular expression operations][1]

  [1]:http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

Comment: то,что предложил panda,выглядит красиво,правда еще не совсем разобрался с управляющими символами,но красиво,чьерт поберри:    >>> import re
>>> text = "<td><span class=small>1.</span><br><a href='/roder/re3rr70' title='0r0t3 (1et).jpg'>picture</a></td>"
>>> d = re.search(r"<a href='(.+?)' title='(.+?)'>.*</a>", text)
>>> print 'http:/%s/%s' % (d.group(1), d.group(2))
http://roder/re3rr70/0r0t3 (1et).jpg

Comment: мне было не понятно,как добавить в условие title,теперь разобрался,что надо было вписать title='(.+?)'>.*</a>"

Comment: > [^>] означает любой символ, кроме '>'. Это нужно, чтобы не прочитать лишнего. 

Внутри кавычек это совершенно бессмысленно, логичнее бы было бы написать выражение "любой символ кроме кавычки" или "любой символ кроме кавычки либо экранированная кавычка" (см. комментарий выше)

Answer (score 5):

Лучше не стоит парсить HTML регэкспами. Начиная с того, что, собственно, HTML не регулярен (хотя нынешние регэкспы тоже, хех, Тьюринг-полны), и заканчивая тем, что для такого придуманы lxml или BeautifulSoup.

Вот пример с lxml:

```
[(e.get("href"), e.get("title"))
 for e in lxml.html.fromstring(text)
                   .xpath("//td/span[@class='small']/following-sibling::a")]
```

Comment: а,пояснить это на выше написанном коде можно?

Comment: Ну, парсим HTML-фрагмент вызовом `lxml.html.fromstring()`, выполняем на нем XPath-запрос `//td/span[@class='small']/following-sibling::a` (в любом месте элемент — «`//td`», в нем `span` с атрибутом `class="small"` — «`/span[@class='small']`», и от этого последующий соседний элемент `a` — «`/following-sibling::a`»), итерируем по результату и на каждый элемент результата возвращаем кортеж с атрибутами «`href`» и «`title`».